# JPA Specification - Multiple OR condition and LEFT join on nullable fields

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

Below are my model classes

Customer

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long customerid;

    @NotNull
    String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "phone_no")
    @JsonProperty("phone_no")
    String phoneNo;

    String referer;

    @NotNull
    String email;

    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty(required = false)
    Agent agent;

    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "partner_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty(required = false)
    Partner partner;
}
```

Agent

```
public class Agent extends UserDetails
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long agentid;

    String city;

    String type;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id",nullable=false)
    private User user;
}
```

Partner

```
public class Partner extends UserDetails
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long partnerid;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id",nullable=false)
    private User user;
}
```

Mapped Super class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class UserDetails 
{

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="mobileno")
    String mobileno;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="email")
    String email;
```

Business Logic - A customer will either have 'referer' field populated, else it will be an agent or partner. If he is related to agent, we will have agent_id populated else partner_id populated.

I want to write a specification where it will try to filter based on these optional field. Search should be

IF customer.referer MATCHES OR agent.name MATCHES or partner.name MATCHED -> return record.

I have to perform this search for multiple strings. So, I wrote reusable methods to generate specification. Below is my specification class

```
public class CustomerSpecification {

    SpecificationsBuilder<Customer> specbldr = new SpecificationsBuilder<Customer>();

    public Specification<Customer> getSpecification(FilterDataListV2 filterDataList) throws Exception {
        
        Specification<Customer> finalSpec = null;
        List<String> globalSearch = SpecificationsBuilder.fetchValueFromFilterList(filterDataList, "globalSearch");

        if (globalSearch != null && globalSearch.size() > 0) {
            
            Specification<Customer> internalSpec1 = whereDirectFieldContains(Customer_.REFERER, globalSearch);
            Specification<Customer> internalSpec2 = whereChildFieldContains(Customer_.AGENT, Agent_.NAME, globalSearch);
            Specification<Customer> internalSpec3 = whereChildFieldContains(Customer_.PARTNER, Partner_.NAME, globalSearch);

            Specification<Customer> internalSpec = internalSpec1.or(internalSpec2).or(internalSpec3);

            finalSpec = specbldr.specAndCondition(finalSpec, internalSpec);
        }
        return finalSpec;
    }


    public Specification<Customer> whereDirectFieldContains(String key, List<String> names)
    {
        Specification<Customer> finalSpec = null;
        for (String name : names)
        {
            Specification<Customer> internalSpec = (Root<Customer> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> cb
                    .like(root.get(key), "%" + name + "%");
            finalSpec = specOrCondition(finalSpec, internalSpec);
        }
        return finalSpec;
    }

    public Specification<Customer> whereChildFieldContains(String childTable, String childFiledName, List<String> names)
    {
        Specification<Customer> finalSpec = null;
        for (String name : names)
        {
            Specification<Customer> internalSpec = (Root<Customer> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> cb
                    .like(root.get(childTable).get(childFiledName), "%" + name + "%");
            finalSpec = specOrCondition(finalSpec, internalSpec);
        }
        return finalSpec;
    }
    
    public Specification<Customer> specOrCondition(Specification<Customer> finalSpec, Specification<Customer> internalSpec)
    {
        if (finalSpec == null)
            return internalSpec;
        else
            return finalSpec.or(internalSpec);
    }

    public Specification<Customer> specAndCondition(Specification<Customer> finalSpec, Specification<Customer> internalSpec)
    {
        if (finalSpec == null)
            return internalSpec;
        else
            return finalSpec.and(internalSpec);
    }
}
```

I expected it to return results if any of the field matches with search criteria. However, no records are being returned.

Expected SQL - For 2 search strings

```
SELECT c.* from customer c 
LEFT JOIN agent a on c.agent_id=a.agentid
LEFT JOIN partner p on c.partner_id=p.partnerid
WHERE 
    c.referer LIKE '%MOHAN%' OR c.referer LIKE '%NIRANJAN%'
    OR a.name LIKE '%MOHAN%' OR c.referer LIKE '%NIRANJAN%'
    OR p.name LIKE '%MOHAN%' OR c.referer LIKE '%NIRANJAN%';
```

Generated SQL

```
select
            customer0_.customerid as customer1_3_,
            customer0_.agent_id as agent_id6_3_,
            customer0_.email as email2_3_,
            customer0_.name as name3_3_,
            customer0_.partner_id as partner_7_3_,
            customer0_.phone_no as phone_no4_3_,
            customer0_.referer as referer5_3_ 
        from
            customer customer0_ cross 
        join
            agent agent1_ cross 
        join
            partner partner3_ 
        where
            customer0_.agent_id=agent1_.agentid 
            and customer0_.partner_id=partner3_.partnerid -- This AND condition should not be there
            and (
                customer0_.referer like ? 
                or customer0_.referer like ? 
                or agent1_.name like ? 
                or agent1_.name like ? 
                or partner3_.name like ? 
                or partner3_.name like ?
            ) 
        order by
            customer0_.customerid
```

Can somebody help where am I going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using JoinType.LEFT. Created below reusable generic method to left join entities and it worked

```
public Specification<T> whereDirectFieldLeftJoinContains(String table, String field, List<String> globalSearch) {
        Specification<T> finalSpec = null;
        for (String name : globalSearch)
        {
            Specification<T> internalSpec = (Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> cb
                    .like(root.join(table, JoinType.LEFT).get(field), "%" + name + "%");
            finalSpec = specOrCondition(finalSpec, internalSpec);
        }
        return finalSpec;
    }
```